# Enabling AAD federated SSO for Google compute engine hosted app

Tags: single-sign-on, google-compute-engine, azure-active-directory, appsource

I have a Webapp hosted on Google compute engine. I am trying to list it on Microsoft AppSource. One of the mandatory conditions for listing is enabling Azure Active Directory federated Single Sign-on (AAD federated SSO) for the app.

Google Cloud platform supports SAML 2.0-based SSO. Hence technically this should be possible. Has anybody tried it and any has experiences to share. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order for an application to integrate with Azure Active Directory - it is not required that you have an Azure Subscription, or even Azure Active Directory (specially if your application is a [multi-tenant application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-appsource-certified#multi-tenant-applications)) - you can host your application anywhere.

For AppSource, as long as your app integrates with Azure Active Directory, then you are able to list your app on AppSource - which means that the application does not need to be hosted in Azure. AppSource also requires Open Id Connect - SAML would not qualify. For more details please see [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-appsource-certified).

To make it easier to test the Azure AD integration in your application, you can create/ use a [test tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-howto-tenant#use-an-msa-azure-subscription) with a Microsoft personal account (MSA), as well as use this MSA account to register your application for OAUTH2 flow.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to use GCP's SSO. This is really designed to allow your developers to use your organization's auth system while working on GCP. This is different than allowing your *users* to use *their organization's* AD while working within your web app.

Instead, I suggest you look to see if anyone has built AD or SAML integration for the framework your webapp is built with, or look to implementing it yourself. This allows the SSO auth to be used for the app itself, instead of in accessing GCP APIs.